# How to build a jar file on Azure and copy to Artifactory?

Tags: java, azure, azure-pipelines, artifactory

I have an Azure pipeline that is supposed to be building my java code with maven.  The YAML looks like this:

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/<project-name>/pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
     #allowBrokenSymlinks: 
    
# Copy jar file from a source folder to a target folder
- task: CopyFiles@1
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/<project-name>/target'
    contents: 'filename.jar' 
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    cleanTargetFolder: false # Optional
    overWrite: true # Optional
```

I was expecting there to be a jar file in the /target but nothing shows up there.  Then, since there is no jar file created, the copy to Artifactory doesn't work either.  The pipeline runs without error.  Azure docs are clear as mud.

I'm new to Azure and Artifactory so please keep it simple if you can help!

Comment: SUGGESTION: Enable verbose output from Maven (-X) and look at the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most recommended way is to use the [Artifactory Azure DevOps extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension).
The extension uses the JFrog CLI to build and upload your Maven JARs to Artifactory.

After downloading and installation of the extension, you can configure your pipeline in 2 steps

1. Configure [Artifactory service connection](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-ConfiguringtheJFrogArtifactoryandJFrogDistributionServiceConnection).
2. In your pipeline, configure [Artifactory Maven](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-TriggeringMavenBuilds) build. To Make it upload the JARs to Artifactory, please run the Maven `install` goal instead of `package`.

For more information see:

1. [Extension documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension)
2. [Webinar](https://jfrog.com/webinar/effective-ci-cd-with-azure-devops-and-the-jfrog-platform/)
3. General information about the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI).

Comment: I was stuck on configuring Artifactory service connection.  Fortunately, a colleague had one already configured and with the right permissions.  Now it's failing with "can't download node.js.  Unknown host".  But that's a different issue so I'll accept your answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Wild Card for fetching the jar?

Example:

```
 - task: CopyFiles@1
   inputs:
     sourceFolder: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/<project-name>/target'
     contents: *.jar
     targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     cleanTargetFolder: false # Optional
     overWrite: true # Optional
```